# How to determine if remoting channel is already registered

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

In my ASP.NET application, I have a line in the global application start event that configures the client remoting channel by calling RemotingConfiguration.Configure().

This works well the first time, but when my web application gets recycled, the application start event is fired again causing the following remoting exception:

Remoting configuration failed with the exception 'System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: The channel 'tcp' is already registered.

I would like to detect if the channel is already configured so that I can avoid getting this exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.channelservices.registeredchannels(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I've been having this problem too.

The trouble is that you can stop the application that called RemotingConfiguration.Configure() but that doesn't make the channel available. Its something to do with ports or it might just be the name of the channel, I'm not sure.

The solution I found which seems to work is to get the registered channels and unregister the channel you want to remove.

Here is some code

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(appConfig, false);

// do this to unregister the channel
IChannel[] regChannels = ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels;
IChannel channel = (IChannel)ChannelServices.GetChannel(regChannels[0].ChannelName);

ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(channel);

RemotingConfiguration.Configure(appConfig, false); // this is just a test to see if we get an error
```

I hope this works for you, it has for me

Answer (score 0):

But what would you do if you found it was already registered?

In any case, I just wanted to make sure you knew that .NET Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF.

Comment: If I knew that it was already registered, I would not call RemotingConfiguration.Configure() to avoid the exception.

Comment: But it wouldn't be registered to _you_, would it?

Comment: It would be registered to our software. My guess is that the first time we register the remoting channel, it becomes registered for the w3wp.exe process. Since the process does not get restarted when the web app recycles, the second configuration call from the application_start event causes an exception.

Comment: Have you tried that? Because I bet the registration takes effect per-AppDomain. I bet it involves data structures mapping between the remoted types and the proxy types to be instantiated instead of them. Besides, Processes don't matter much to .NET. Most things are in terms of AppDomain and Thread.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this John. I can reliably repeat this behavior by rebuilding my app and then refreshing from the browser. I can see the application is restarted and the exception is thrown. BTW - this is something I am seeing with IIS7 with an integrated pipeline (which I'm new to). I don't remember seeing this in previous versions of IIS.

Comment: @Randy: I don't doubt the exception is thrown; I doubt whether you'll be able to use the registration if the channel is in use. Try the ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels property, but that, too. may be per-AppDomain. Otherwise, try catching the exception and ignoring it. See if remoting stil works for you after that.